# How to write a pr2 controller like base_controller

Tags: microcontroller, plugin, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all，

I want to write a pr2 controller to control the robot manipulators by sending commands in another executing file (not in command line). But the tutorials [link text](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller) did everything inside the plugin. I saw the way to use the base_controller to control the pose of the robot. It is the way I want to control the robot. [link text](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Using%20the%20base%20controller%20with%20odometry%20and%20transform%20information) But I don't know how to write a controller like the base_controller. If anyone knows how to do that, please give me some help. I really appreciate that.

Thanks,

Xiaolong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50386/how-to-write-a-pr2-controller-like-base_controller/) by [Xiaolong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3725/xiaolong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used a topic to communicate between the execute file and controller plugin. So it works.

---

Originally posted by [Xiaolong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3725/xiaolong/) with karma: 66 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0